# using array data from database for send email to multiple recipients codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, email

I have tried send email to multiple recipients. I input the recipients into an array, like this:

```
$recipients = array(
            'email1@host.com',
            'email2@host.com',
            'email3@host.com'
        );
```

And it works nice.

Now I need to get the email address form database, and when I run it, it shows error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 795

I tried to see the array from the database, and it looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [email] => vikki2@afteroffice.com ) [1] => Array ( [email] => nanapuspita05@hotmail.com ) )
```

Here are the function to send email:

```
function send_bulk_mail() {
        $from = 'email@email.com';
        $to = 'email1@email.com';
        $search_by = $this->input->post('search_by');
        $search_field = $this->input->post('search_field');
        $recipients = $this->company_model->get_email($search_by, $search_field);;
        $subject = $this->input->post('subject');
        $message = $this->input->post('message');

        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->from($from);
        $this->email->to($to);
        $this->email->bcc($recipients);
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);
        $this->email->send();

        redirect(base_url('index.php/company'));
    }
```

Is there any solution to change the array? Or for change the rules in `libraries/email.php`

This is the function in libraries/email.php:

```
public function clean_email($email)
    {
        if ( ! is_array($email))
        {
            if (preg_match('/\<(.*)\>/', $email, $match))
            {
                return $match['1'];
            }
            else
            {
                return $email;
            }
        }

        $clean_email = array();

        foreach ($email as $addy)
        {
            if (preg_match( '/\<(.*)\>/', $addy, $match))
            {
                $clean_email[] = $match['1'];
            }
            else
            {
                $clean_email[] = $addy;
            }
        }

        return $clean_email;
    }
```

Thank you...

Comment: Can you paste the code where it's breaking? libraries/Email.php line 795 (the whole enclosing function)

Comment: Done, sir. Please check it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **$recipients** you retrived from DB is an array with each element is an **array**, while the **$recipients** you described below is an array with each element is a **string**. Try to make an array with each element is a string when you retrive from DB like this :

```
$recipient_array = $this->company_model->get_email($search_by, $search_field);
$recipients = array();
foreach($recipient_array as $key => $value)　{
     $recipients[] = $value['email'];
}
```

Comment: I have tried to call the array result using this code `print_r($recipients);` and the result still same with the above.

Answer (score 0):

preg_match expects two strings and then an array.  (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).  The error seems to indicate that it's not getting a properly formatted array as the second parameter.

Based on the proper formatting of an array (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) compared to your array output it seems as if you are giving it an array of arrays that enumerated with the 'email' index.  (much like the 'fruits' example in the provided link).